# Stuck my page at some string without error

Tags: javascript

For some reason, this makes my page stuck and doesn't show the `alert`

I'm trying to replace `"` with `\"` in some text.

**Example Parameters**

`Search = "`

`Replace = \"`

`Text = "hello world"`

**Note** 
*The `Text` is `"hello world"` **not** `hello world`*

The expected output (`Text`) should be `\"hello world\"`

```js
var Search = prompt("What To Search?"); // It will be the sign "
var Replace = prompt("What Sign To Replace?"); // It will be the sign \"
var Text = prompt("Write Text Here");
while(Text.includes(Search))
{
    Text=Text.replace(Search,Replace);
} // It's didn't replace all so I did this
alert(Text);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets stuck because you are going in an infinite loop

Use this

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.split(search).join(replacement);
};

var Search=prompt("What To Search?"); // It will be the sign "
var Replace=prompt("What Sign To Replace?"); // It will be the sign \"
var Text=prompt("Write Text Here");

            Text=Text.replaceAll(Search,Replace);

alert(Text);
```

Now try

```
Text=Text.replaceAll(Search,Replace);
```

instead of

```
Text=Text.replace(Search,Replace);
```

[See working Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/surajmahajan007/m3486cku/)

Answer (score 2):

It gets stuck because you are going in a infinite loop, because you are creating the same string you are replacing with your replace statement.

you can use replace as given in other answers, you can also use a combination of split and join to do this.

```js
var Search = prompt("What To Search?"); // It will be the sign "
var Replace = prompt("What Sign To Replace?"); // It will be the sign \"
var Text = prompt("Write Text Here");
Text = Text.split(Search).join(Replace);
alert(Text);
```

Comment: So do you have a solution?

Comment: @casraf was working on a solution, it is updated now.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you're replacing a string with another one that contains it, the condition for the while loop will stay true and obviously it will keep looping and not stop... You use a regular expression to replace globally, which means it will replace all occurrences at once:

```js
var Search = prompt("What To Search?"); // It will be the sign "
var Replace = prompt("What Sign To Replace?"); // It will be the sign \"
var Text = prompt("Write Text Here");
Text = Text.replace(new RegExp(Search, 'g'), Replace);
alert(Text);
```

Naturally you might want to perform a validation or escaping of the text in some cases

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is you are replacing the string with the same string. so the while loop will becoming true always.
You can simply use regular expressions here

```
var re = new RegExp(Replace, 'g');
Search = Search.replace(re,Text);
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/op8t95bh/) is a jsfiddle for you